# What is the past participle of the verb to get?

Tags: verbs, tenses, past-participles

I get often confused with the verb **to get** in the past tenses. I see gotten, got, etc. Could someone kindly clarify with some few examples?

Shall I say:

```
I have got
```

or

```
I have gotten
```

Comment: João, if the linked duplicate does not answer your question, please edit it and we can nominate yours for re-opening. The short story is that *have got* is the dominant form outside North America, but within North America there is a distinction in sense between *have got* indicating simple possession and *have gotten* indicating having received something. No one would therefore ever say *“I have *gotten one thing to tell you”*: that one has to be *have got*.

Comment: It does solve, thank you. I previously did a search though I didn't find it.